# The gap still keeps 100% in running Gurobi model

Tags: optimization, gurobi

I am solving a mixed-integer linear programming model on Python platform using the solver Gurobi. However, The gap of the model still keeps 100 % during the long-running time.
I am trying to use the codes to limit the running time. The solution is found, but I don't know why the gap in the model doesn't reduce.
I have attached the file below.
Could you help me to fix this problem?
Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also add a small objective offset to enforce a non-zero dual bound. This will enable a more expressive gap. You could use the [ObjCon](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/objcon.html) model attribute to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! While still appreciated, to say thanks you don't post a new comment but upvote the respective answer or comment. You should also mark one answer as the preferred one by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

The gap is defined as:

```
gap = |bestfound - bestbound|/|bestfound|
```

(see the Gurobi documentation).

The best bound in your screenshot stays at 0, so the gap does not change and remains 100%.

Comment: Thank you for your response!! I would like to know that Do any codes improve the gap in this model? Because the running time is too long (more than 2 days). The gap in the model still remains 100%.

Comment: Option MipFocus can help. But most impactful is to develop a better formulation.